# Как сделать перемещение относительно прямой ax + by + c = 0, аффинные преобразования

Tags: c#, графика, геометрия, преобразование, picturebox

**Само задание:** 
Задан треугольник. Реализовать его движение на основе зеркального отражения относительно произвольной прямой `ax + by + c = 0`, коэффициенты которой вводятся пользователем.

**Что уже сделал:** 
Считываю из полей на форме координаты трех точек треугольника. 
Помещая их в объекты класса `Point` (`left(x, y)`, `top(x, y)`, `right(x, y)`).

Делаю массив `points` из точек треугольника:

```
Point[] points = new Point[3] { left, top, right };
```

Рисую декартову систему координат:

```
DrawField();
DrawCoordinateSystem();
```

Рисую треугольник:

```
graph.FillPolygon(Brushes.ForestGreen, points);
```

Делаю зеркальное отражение треугольника: 
(насколько я понял, нужно просто поменять знак у всех точек `Y`)

```
Point[] pointsCopy = (Point[]) points.Clone();

for (int i = 0; i  pointsCopy.Length; i++)
    pointsCopy[i].Y = -pointsCopy[i].Y;

graph.FillPolygon(Brushes.RoyalBlue, pointsCopy);
```

Считываю из полей на форме коэффициенты (`a`, `b`, `c`) для уравнения `ax + by + c = 0`. 
 

Вот что получилось: 
[image: Affine transformation of triangle]

**Вопрос:** 
Подскажите как мне дальше его перемещать относительно прямой `ax + by + c = 0` ?

Comment: http://sernam.ru/book_mm3d.php?id=46

Comment: «насколько я понял, нужно просто поменять знак у всех точек Y» — неправильно поняли. Это зеркально отображает относительно оси Ox, а вам нужно относительно прямой `ax + by + c = 0 `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как я разобрался со своей задачей, может кому пригодится.

---

Чтобы выполнить отражение треугольника относительно произвольной прямой, нужно выполнить конкретные действия:

- перемещение линии и треугольника таким образом, чтобы линия прошла через начало координат;
- поворот линии и треугольника вокруг точки начала координат до совпадения с координатной осью X;
- отражение относительно координатной оси;
- обратный поворот вокруг начала координат;
- перемещение в исходное положение.

В матричном виде данное преобразование имеет представление 
 
`[T] = [T'] [R] [R'] [R^(-1)] [T'^(-1)]`,
где T' - матрица перемещения, R - матрица поворота вокруг начала координат, R' - матрица отражения.

---

Уравнение `ax + by + c = 0`, можно привести к виду:

```
by = -ax - c
y = -a/b x - c/b
```

Из него находем две точки линии `A`, `B`:

```
Point A = new Point( -width, -(a / b) * -width - c / b );
Point B = new Point( width, -(a / b) * width - c / b );
```

Где `a`, `b`, `c` - коэффициенты считанные с полей на форме, `width` - расстояние от начала canvas к середине (`width = Canvas.Width / 2`), где x = 0.

В результате есть прямая `L`, проходящая через всю систему координат. 
 Запишем ее в матричном виде:

```
float[,] L = new float[2, 3] {
    { A.X, A.Y, 1 },
    { B.X, B.Y, 1 }
};
```

---

Так же запишем матрицу `X` из массива точек треугольника `points`:

```
float[,] X = new float[3, 3] {
    { points[0].X, points[0].Y, 1 },
    { points[1].X, points[1].Y, 1 },
    { points[2].X, points[2].Y, 1 }
};
```

---

Теперь делаем аффинные преобразования с помощью умножения матриц. 
Для умножения будем использовать метод `MultiplyMatrix`

```
private static float[,] MultiplyMatrix(float[,] a, float[,] b)
{
    float[,] product = new float[a.GetLength(0), b.GetLength(1)];

    for (int row = 0; row  product.GetLength(0); row++)
        for (int col = 0; col  product.GetLength(1); col++)
            // Multiply the row of A by the column of B
            for (int inner = 0; inner  a.GetLength(1); inner++)
                product[row, col] += a[row, inner] * b[inner, col];

    return product;
}
```

1) Для перемещения линии и треугольника таким образом, чтобы линия прошла через начало координат находем позицию `y` при `x = 0`:

```
float ys = -(a / b) * 0 - c / b;
```

Перемещаем линию и треугольник в начало координат с помощью матрицы перемещения:

```
float[,] T = new float[3, 3] {
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, -ys, 1 }
};

L = MultiplyMatrix(L, T);
X = MultiplyMatrix(X, T);
```

2) Делаем поворот линии и треугольника вокруг точки начала координат до совпадения с координатной осью `X`. Для этого находим под каким углом находится линия относительно оси `X`:

```
double radians = Math.Atan(-(a / b));
```

И поворачиваем с помощью матрицы поворота вокруг начала координат:

```
float[,] R = new float[3, 3] {
    { Math.Cos(radians), -Math.Sin(radians), 0 }, 
    { Math.Sin(radians), Math.Cos(radians), 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 }
};

L = MultiplyMatrix(L, R);
X = MultiplyMatrix(X, R);
```

3) Отражаем треугольник относительно координатной оси с помощью матрицы отражения:

```
float[,] Rr = new float[3, 3] {
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, -1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 }
};

X = MultiplyMatrix(X, Rr);
```

4) Делаем обратный поворот вокруг начала координат:

```
float[,] Rh = new float[3, 3] {
    { Math.Cos(radians), Math.Sin(radians), 0 },
    { -Math.Sin(radians), Math.Cos(radians), 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 }
};

L = MultiplyMatrix(L, Rh);
X = MultiplyMatrix(X, Rh);
```

5) Делаем перемещение в исходное положение:

```
float[,] Th = new float[3, 3] {
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, ys, 1 }
};

L = MultiplyMatrix(L, Th);
X = MultiplyMatrix(X, Th);
```

---

Присвоем новые значения для массива `points`:

```
for (int i = 0; i  p.Length; i++)
{
    points[i].X = X[i, 0];
    points[i].Y = X[i, 1];
}
```

Рисуем треугольник с новыми координатами:

```
graph.FillPolygon(Brushes.RoyalBlue, points);
```

---

[image: Affine transformation]

Comment: "нужно выполнить конкретные действия..." Это называется "чесать левое ухо правой ногой". Ничего подобного делать не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

точку отраженного треугольника (многоугольника) можно рассчитать следующим образом:

```
x = A.x + (A.x - P0.x)
y = A.y + (A.y - P0.y)
```

где,

```
      |B*P0.x + C*P0.y,  C|
      |C*P1.x - B*P1.y, -B|
 A.x = --------------------- ,
          -B*B - C*C

      |B,  B*P0.x + C*P0.y|
      |C,  C*P1.y - B*P1.y|
 A.y = ---------------------
          -B*B - C*C

 B = P2.x - P1.x
 C = P2.y - P1.y
```

`P0` - точка многоугольника,

`P1, P2` - точки образующие прямую `(ax + by + c = 0)`

За подробными пояснениями по поводу откуда взялись эти формулы, посмотрите мой ответ на подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602336/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B/603289#603289)

[визуализация](https://jsfiddle.net/20fpr170/145/)

Comment: Я уже решил свой вопрос, но все равно спасибо. Описал в виде ответа.

Comment: Это решение занимается поиском точек-проекций на прямую. Если эти точки действительно нужны - то это полезно. Но если интересует только отражение, то усилия, затраченные на поиск точек-проекций, на самом деле избыточны.

Comment: @AnT согласен, но каких-то запредельных усилий там не было вовсе - решалась система 2 ух уравнений с 2 мя неизвестными всего лишь

Answer (score 2):

В таких задачах проще всего работать с векторным представлением, оно очень наглядно и доступно для понимания головой. Никаких сложных формул расчётов, поворотов, матриц знать не надо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`A` это точка, `B` - вектор, вмести они задают прямую от которой надо зеркально отобразить.

Формула этой прямой: `A + B * t`

Точка `C` и вектор `D` задают перпендикулярную прямую.
Точка `C` известна из условия, это одна из точек треугольника. Вектор D тоже известен это вектор перпендикулярный вектору `B`, то есть имеет координаты `By,-Bx`, либо `-By,Bx`, нам подойдёт любой.

Составляем уравнение точки пересечения

```
Ax + Bx * t = Cx + Dx * f
Ay + By * t = Cy + Dy * f
```

`t` и `f` это коэффициенты на которые мы умножаем вектора B и D что бы попасть в точку пересечения, они же наши переменные которые нам и надо найти.

подставляем вместо `Dx,Dy` компоненты вычисленные на основе `B`, то есть перпендикулярный ему вектор.

```
Ax + Bx * t = Cx - By * f
Ay + By * t = Cy + Bx * f
```

решаем уравнение и находим коэффициент `f`. Он то нам и нужен.

Зеркальная точка к точке `C`, это `C + 2 * f * D`

По координатно

```
x = Cx + 2 * f * Dx
y = Cy + 2 * f * Dy;
```

Comment: Можно чуть больше деталей ? А то пока не очень понимаю

Comment: @TarasKoval тогда я уточню задачу, нужно отобразить относительно прямой и потом анимировать движение параллельно прямой?

Comment: @TarasKova или просто зеркально отобразить?

Comment: Нужно просто зеркально отобразить

Comment: @TarasKoval хорошо, сейчас объясню

Comment: @TarasKoval сделал

Answer (score 2):

С "математической" точки зрения для отражения точки `(Px, Py)` относительно прямой `A * x + B * y + C = 0` можно поступить так:

1. Нормализуем уравнение прямой, т.е. делим все коэффициенты уравнения на длину вектора нормали `(A, B)`. Получаем нормализованное уравнение

   ```
   A' * x + B' * y + C' = 0
   ```
2. Вычисляем *знаковое* расстояние от точки `(Px, Py)` до прямой

   ```
   D = A' * Px + B' * Py + C'
   ```
3. Переносим точку `(Px, Py)` на расстояние `2D` против направления вектора нормали `(A', B')`

   ```
   Px' = Px - 2 * A' * D
   Py' = Py - 2 * B' * D
   ```

Готово - мы получили зеркально отраженную точку `(Px', Py')`.

С практической точки зрения вместо предварительной нормализации уравнения на шаге 1 лучше воспользоваться ненормализованными коэффициентами `A`, `B` и `C` и затем просто учесть длину вектора на шаге 3 - это избавляет от необходимости вычислять квадратный корень для вычисления длины и позволяет решать задачу в целых числах

```
D = A * Px + B * Py + C
L = A * A + B * B;
Px' = Px - 2 * A * D / L
Py' = Py - 2 * B * D / L
```